# Configuring service binding in wcf 4.0

Tags: wcf, web-services

I'm trying to add to the generated wcf 4.0 web config some binding configurations for my service.
For some reason, after I publish the service to the IIS and logging to the service wsdl, I still see the old configurations (basicHttpBinding instead wsHttpBinding).

Here is my code:

Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="PDFServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="None"/>

        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="PDFService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/PDFService/PDFService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PDFServiceBinding"
          contract="PDF.Service.IPDFService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/PDFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

PDFService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace PDF.Service
{    
    public class PDFService : IPDFService
    {
         ...     
    }
}
```

IPDFService.cs

```
namespace PDF.Service
{    
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPDFService
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The wsdl after the publish:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <wsdl:definitions name="PDFService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
- <wsdl:types>
- <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/PDFService/PDFService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/PDFService/PDFService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/PDFService/PDFService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PDF" /> 
  </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
- <wsdl:message name="IPDFService_Save_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Save" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IPDFService_Save_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaveResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:portType name="IPDFService">
- <wsdl:operation name="Save">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPDFService/Save" message="tns:IPDFService_Save_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPDFService/SaveResponse" message="tns:IPDFService_Save_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
- <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPDFService" type="tns:IPDFService">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="Save">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPDFService/Save" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <wsdl:service name="PDFService">
- <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IPDFService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IPDFService">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost/PDFService/PDFService.svc" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: I've tried to delete the IIS application and re-publish but still got the same results..

Comment: I don't have a service reference. I'm browsing to the wsdl at: http://localhost/PDFService/PDFService.svc?wsdl and it's not changed.

Comment: Can you try to host that in your local IIS and see if the wsdl has wsHttpBinding instead of BasicHttpBinding. If in your local you can see wsHttpBinding i would copy the contents of the output directory onto the remote server IIS to make sure its not a problem during publish.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the comment. Even when running locally: (Right click on PDFService.svc --> View in browser), I still don't see the wsHttpBinding i've made.
Please notice: 
1. When I change the bindingConfiguration to "PDFServiceBinding1" (binding configuration that does not exist) - I can't run the service. 
2. When I change the service name to "PDFService1", I can't find in the wsdl "PDFService1", but do find "PDFService"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Service element should be as below:

```
<service name="PDF.Service.PDFService">         
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PDFServiceBinding" contract="PDF.Service.IPDFService" />         
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />         
</service>
```

NOTE: your are missing to provide namespace in your service name. The name of the service should be fully qualified.